# MFC does not draw rectangular edges with LineTo

Tags: mfc, visual-c++-2012

I have a Problem when drawing with the MFC CDC class and the LineTo and MoveTo function.
The CDC Object doesn't begin at the point where I move the Pointer and leaves the first Pixel blanc like in the center of the image. When I draw around a corner like on the left side of the image it is clear that the CDC object leaves the outmost pixel free.
I did try to load a custom brush but had no different results.

[image: Edge example]

```
    memDC.FillSolidRect(client, BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    CPen penBorder(PS_ENDCAP_SQUARE | PS_SOLID, BORDER_WIDTH, BORDER_COLOR);
    //Draw the Horizontal line for the Status Bar
    CPen* oldPen = memDC.SelectObject(&penBorder);
    memDC.MoveTo(client.left + 0.5f * BORDER_WIDTH, client.top + 0.5f * BORDER_WIDTH);
    memDC.LineTo(client.Width() - 0.5f * BORDER_WIDTH, client.top + 0.5f * BORDER_WIDTH);
    CPen penRecess(PS_ENDCAP_SQUARE | PS_SOLID, BORDER_WIDTH, RECESS_COLOR);
    //Draw the recess
    memDC.SelectObject(&penRecess);
    memDC.MoveTo(client.left + 1.5f * BORDER_WIDTH, client.top + 1.5f * BORDER_WIDTH);
    memDC.LineTo(client.Width() - 0.5f * BORDER_WIDTH, client.top + 1.5f * BORDER_WIDTH);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with MFC but is inherent in the underlying Windows GDI function. The [documentation for `LineTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145029%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

> The LineTo function draws a line from the current position up to, but not including, the specified point.

If you need the last point drawn, you should do a second `LineTo` one pixel away from the first.